# Changing table cell colors in Javascript without the use of id's

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small project where I'd like to change the background color of a table's cells while the mouse hovers over each cell.  I'm able to do it with an individual cell with document.getElementById("cell1"); etc. but haven't found a way to make life easier by selecting all of the td tags and avoiding giving each cell its own id.  I've tried document.getElementsByTagName but the console returns that cell.addEventListener is not a function.  I must be using the selectors wrong or am not understanding the correct usage of event handling. I've found a similar question on here but it doesn't address using solely javascript which i'd like to do.

```
var cell = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

cell.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor="red";

cell.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor="";
})
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing this with CSS?

Comment: or using a JS library (eg. jQuery: https://jquery.com/)

Comment: @AdamMichalik no. you don't need an entire library for basic event handling. that's bloating your code for no reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be iterating the set. "The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

```
for(var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++){
    cell[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor="red";
    };
    cell[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor="";
    });
}
```

However, a better way to do this would be a simple hover rule in css

```
td:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I prefer `cell.forEach(function() { ... });` but of course the prototype iteration is slower (but "safer") and more advanced. but good answer, +1

Comment: @SterlingArcher - forEach also requires either using a plugin to ensure older browser support or an explanation about best practice when choosing a newer technology. I mean, really you could also have gone with the arrow function to show where the newest form is.

Comment: Of course, browser compatibility is always a potential issue

Comment: `cell.forEach(c => { c.add...; });` , I wish we could use this now, I really like lambda expressions in other languages

Comment: Right? New browsers I believe handle lambdas just fine, but anything beyond shiniest build is a risk

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was trying to accomplish.  I wanted to avoid CSS and jQuery solely to try and aid my understand of javascript. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4):

Why not CSS? The `:hover` pseudo class is much easier and conserves code length and complexity, and is ultimately faster.

```
td:hover{ /* insert proper selector here */
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").on("mouseover mouseout", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("red");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwagtd0d/1

You can add and remove classes with jQuery by listening for events, but it's easiest to do this with css.

```
td:hover
```

JavaScript solution

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

This returns a collection of `td` elements. We can now iterate through this selection.

```
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
    cells[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        this.classList.add("red");
    };
    cells[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        this.classList.remove("red");
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qknjyaaw/

Comment: The question was not tagged jQuery, please don't introduce unnecessary libraries for trivial issues.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. It is thus part of JavaScript.

Comment: That is completely irrelevant to my statement? I never said jQuery wasn't JavaScript.

Comment: introducing new dependencies which may or may not be in scope for the OP is discouraged. If there is no library tag, often you should not answer using a lib.. Otherwise we would have vanilla answers, jQuery answers, underscore answers, Zepto answers, etc..

Comment: as a suggestion, do not define functions in a loop. store the mouseover and mouseout functions outside of the loop and assign them inside. Alternatively delegate from a common parent and do not assign in the loop.